# WooCommerce free shipping to members results in error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, membership, shipping-method

I have this issue where I want for members to receive free delivery. I have figured out how to do that, but now I get an error on the page.

The error is:

```
The WC_Cart->taxes function is deprecated since version 3.2. Replace 
with getters (WC_Cart::get_cart_contents_taxes()) and setters 
(WC_Cart::set_cart_contents_taxes())., referer:
```

This is the code that generates the problem:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite_fedex', 100, 2);
  function test_overwrite_fedex($rates,$package) 
    {
      $memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships();
      if (WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() === 'DK' && !empty($memberships))
        {
          foreach ($rates as $rate) 
            {
              //Set the TAX
              $rate->taxes[1] = 0;
            }
        }
        return $rates;
    }
```

I have tried with:

```
$rate->set_shipping_total('0');
WC()->cart->set_shipping_total('0');
$rate = WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();
```

And still no luck.